# how can hold node in tree view when i hover on it in c# windows form

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

As an example: I have in my tree view ids for employees. When hovering the mouse on specific id, I want to show a tool tip which contains the name of the employer (from my database). So I want to hold the item which hovers over it.

Comment: A simple way is to fill the Nodes' ToolTips when filling the TreeView. This way you won't have to make the trip to the DBMS all the time..

Comment: i wasn't mean how fill tree view nodes i just mean how show tool tip for node when i hover on this node
Any way i know the answer just now i can hold the node when mouse hover on it by
use event handler 
for example(e.node) inside mouse hover event
thank you for your interested

Comment: Well, there are nodes there, right? So when you create one, don't you already have the info you want to show in the tooltip? If not you will need to do the query. But how can we help there, not knowing anything about your data or how you create the nodes???

Comment: Ah, you simply meant how to make the tooltip show at all? See my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added `Tooltip` strings to your nodes they will show when the user hovers over a `Node`.

For this to work you (or the user, if you give him this option) must turn on the `TreeView.ShowNodeToolTip` property:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Knoten0");
TreeNode n = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Knoten1");
n.ToolTipText = "T'm a ToolTip :-)";
//..
treeView1.ShowNodeToolTip = true;      // <<-----
```

[image]

I suggest to consider letting the users turn this off again, as it often interferes with the normal use of the tree..

Answer (score 0):

that what i meant, this the answer for my question method show tool tip from database *** when i hover mouse on specific node*** show tool tip just for this node

```
    public void showTipsTree(TreeView treeView1, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e, 
                int imageindex, string tooltipField, string nameTable, string orginalField)
    {
        treeView1.ShowNodeToolTips = true;
        if (e.Node.SelectedImageIndex == imageindex)
        {
            string q = e.Node.ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection1.x);
            conn.Open();
            string[] a = q.Split();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format(
     "select {1} from {2} where {3}={0}", a[1],tooltipField,nameTable,orginalField), conn);
            e.Node.ToolTipText = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: A tooltip is __always__ shown for a specific node if you have set one. The way you do it now means __repeately__ going to the dbms for a piece of data you only ought to retrieve __once__. Bad solution!

Comment: so what the best solution in your opinion for this situation

Comment: What I told you in my very first comment: Fill in the data when you create the nodes! Read in all in __one__ `select` statement and set up the Nodes to hold the Text you want and the ToolTip you want. After the Treeview is filled no more trips to the db!

Answer (score 0):

i had better answer instead go trips for db ever mouse hover 
the solution fill tool tips for all nodes when i do specific thing like click on refresh button like method below:

```
        static public void showTipsTree(TreeView treeView1, string tooltipField_toMainNodes, string nameTable_toMainNodes, string orginalField_toMainNodes, string tooltipField_toSubNodes, string nameTable_toSubNodes, string orginalField_toSubNodes)
    {
        treeView1.ShowNodeToolTips = true;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection1.x);
        conn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] a = treeView1.Nodes[i].ToString().Split();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("select {0} from {1} where {2}={3}", tooltipField_toMainNodes, nameTable_toMainNodes, orginalField_toMainNodes, a[1]), conn);
            treeView1.Nodes[i].ToolTipText = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Count; j++)
            {
                string[] a2 = treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].ToString().Split();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(String.Format("select {0} from {1} where {2}={3}", tooltipField_toSubNodes, nameTable_toSubNodes, orginalField_toSubNodes, a2[1]), conn);
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].ToolTipText = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```